# How to implement types like MapK in Scala 3 / Dotty?

Tags: scala, existential-type, higher-kinded-types, scala-3, dotty

I am trying and failing to get something like this to work in Scala 3:

```scala
type TupleK[K[*], V[*], A] = (K[A], V[A]) 

final class MapK[K[*], V[*]] private (val rawMap: Map[K[?], V[?]]) {
    
  def foreach(f: TupleK[K, V, ?] => Unit): Unit = {
    rawMap.foreach(f.asInstanceOf[Tuple2[K[?], V[?]] => Any])
  }
}

object MapK {
  
  def apply[K[*], V[*]](entries: TupleK[K, V, ?]*): MapK[K, V] = {
    new MapK[K, V](Map(entries: _*))
  }
}
```

With usage like this:

```scala
class Key[A]()
  
type Id[A] = A
  
val intKey = Key[Int]
val strKey = Key[String]

MapK[Key, Id](intKey -> 1, strKey -> "a")
```

In Scala 2 that works, just need to adjust syntax by replacing `*` and `?` with `_` (except in `_*` of course).

In Scala 3 however basically every line errors with "unreducible application of higher-kinded type  to wildcard arguments": [Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/e3YktKaeRYuam9lhKYDvhQ).

The docs say that existential types have been [dropped](https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/dropped-features/existential-types.html) in Scala 3, however they don't really give any non-trivial examples of how to deal with this.

The docs mention that "Existential types largely overlap with path-dependent types" – can this MapK be implemented with path-dependent types? I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67148882/how-do-existential-types-overlap-with-path-dependent-types) but didn't understand how to apply that, or whether it's possible in my case.

And, if not path dependent types... then what? It seems unlikely that Scala was "simplified" to the point where it's impossible to implement this functionality anymore, so I must be missing something.

ETA: In addition to my own answers below, I made [this repo](https://github.com/raquo/Typegrounds) and wrote [this article](https://dev.to/raquo/existential-crisis-implementing-mapk-in-scala-3-2fo1) about the various approaches to encoding MapK in Scala 3.

Comment: Maybe these would help:
https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/migration/incompat-other-changes.html#wildcard-type-argument
https://users.scala-lang.org/t/solved-unreducible-application-of-higher-kinded-type-to-wildcard-arguments/7257

Comment: I'm probably missing something but I would expect a 3rd type parameter `A` on the `MapK` class

Comment: @GaëlJ No, it's intended as shown. A `MapK[K, V]` can contain `V[A]` for any `A`, as long as it's keyed at `K[A]` with the `A` being the same. It's useful to abstract over keys and values in dynamic structures. See a full implementation here, for example: https://github.com/codedx/mapk

Comment: @MichałPawlicki I've read that, but I don't see how that pattern can be used here. I tried but it just feels like pushing the problem one layer up. It seems to be impossible to implement the `apply` method this way: https://scastie.scala-lang.org/DyYZ33uYRnqBcBv1GV1Xiw

Comment: @GaëlJ I've added an example usage to the question for clarity

Comment: True, it seems really hard to implement a method that accepts multiple tuples parameterized with different types (Int, String, etc.): https://scastie.scala-lang.org/ySM794EuSrqnjdrhHUsxVw Maybe an implementation with `empty` and `updated` methods (like in https://github.com/codedx/mapk) is the way to go.

Comment: I can't confidently explain it, as I'm also still figuring this stuff out, but I had success with `Map[K[Any], V[Any]]` instead of `Map[K[?], V[?]]`. You have to cast the keys, e.g. `key.asInstanceOf[K[Any]]` but it ends up working out.

Comment: Here's my half-working attempt at using path dependent types to solve this: https://gitter.im/scala/scala?at=60b9ffc43c544b55fd916eb1 Less implicits than my answer below, but still issues with type inference, and now also boxing.

Comment: I just released v1.2.0 of https://github.com/codedx/mapk with scala 3 support. I ended up using `Any` instead of `?`/`_` for the wildcard type and it's passing all the tests. I also added a helper syntax for creating entries to use with the MapK.apply method, so you can do `key ~>> value` for when V=cats.Id, or `key ~> value` when V is an actual higher-kinded type.

Comment: @Dylan Thanks for the heads up. I was curious whether you'll have problems migrating. Looks like you managed to do it without anything drastic. If I understand correctly, this is because you use concrete higher kinded types – they just don't need a `forSome` encoding at all, since they're not type aliases but actual real tangible types. I mean like your Tuple2K being a class and not a type alias for a Tuple2.

Comment: Yeah when I get rid of the import of the Cats Tuple2K and define my own as a type alias, my apply method gets the `unreducible application of higher-kinded type [K[_$5], V[_$6], A] =>> (K[A], V[A]) to wildcard arguments` error again.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to produce a working, albeit incredibly annoying, implementation. [This pointer](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/issues/4353#issuecomment-384163401) was especially valuable.

First, a few notes:

- Type inference on this sucks on many levels. All the manual type ascribtions in the tests, and all of the implicit conversions below are needed for this to work.
- Apparently Scala is not smart enough to figure out that `A` and `type Id[A] = A` are functionally the same when looking for implicits, so a combinatorial explosion of ad-hoc implicit conversions are needed. Ugly and not very scalable.
- Observe the different options available in Scala 3: `foreach`, `foreachT`, and `foreachK`. All of them have stylistic tradeoffs.
- If you can improve on any of this, please let me know. This works, but it was so much nicer in Scala 2.

MapK implementation:

```scala
class MapK[K[_], V[_]] protected(protected val rawMap: Map[Type[K], Type[V]]) {

  def apply[A](key: K[A]): V[A] = {
    rawMap(key).asInstanceOf[V[A]]
  }

  def updated[A](key: K[A], value: V[A]): MapK[K, V] = {
    MapK.unsafeCoerce(rawMap.updated(key, value))
  }

  def updated[A](pair: (K[A], V[A])): MapK[K, V] = {
    MapK.unsafeCoerce(rawMap.updated(pair._1, pair._2))
  }

  def foreach[A](f: ((K[A], V[A])) => Unit): Unit = {
    rawMap.foreach(f.asInstanceOf[(([Type[K], Type[V]])) => Any])
  }

  def foreachT(f: Type.Tuple2[K, V] => Unit): Unit = {
    foreach { (k, v) => f((k, v)) }
  }

  def foreachK(f: [A] => (K[A], V[A]) => Unit): Unit = {
    foreach { (k, v) => f(k, v) }
  }

}

object MapK {

  def unsafeCoerce[K[_], V[_]](rawMap: Map[Type[K], Type[V]]): MapK[K, V] = {
    new MapK[K, V](rawMap)
  }

  def apply[K[_], V[_]](entries: Type.Tuple2[K, V]*): MapK[K, V] = {
    new MapK[K, V](Map(entries.asInstanceOf[Seq[(Type[K], Type[V])]]: _*))
  }
}
```

Other methods in MapK that you might want to implement basically follow the same patterns as `foreach`, `foreachT`, or `foreachK`.

And now, usage:

```scala
  def test(caption: String)(code: => Unit): Unit = code

  def assertEquals[A](a: A, b: A): Unit = assert(a == b)

  case class Key[A](label: String, default: A)

  val boolKey = Key[Boolean]("bool", false)

  val intKey = Key[Int]("int", 0)

  val strKey = Key[String]("str", "")

  val optionMap = MapK[Key, Option](boolKey -> Some(true), intKey -> Some(1), strKey -> Option("a"), strKey -> None)

  val idMap = MapK[Key, Id](boolKey -> true, intKey -> 1, strKey -> "hello")

  val expectedOptionValues = List[Type.Tuple3[Key, Option, Id]](
    (boolKey, Some(true), false),
    (intKey, Some(1), 0),
    (strKey, None, "")
  )

  val expectedIdValues = List[Type.Tuple3[Key, Id, Id]](
    (boolKey, true, false),
    (intKey, 1, 0),
    (strKey, "hello", "")
  )

  test("optionMap - apply & updated") {
    assertEquals(optionMap(intKey), Some(1))
    assertEquals(optionMap(strKey), None)
    assertEquals(optionMap.updated(strKey, Some("yo"))(strKey), Some("yo"))
  }

  test("optionMap - foreach") {
    var values: List[Type.Tuple3[Key, Option, Id]] = Nil

    optionMap.foreach { (k, v) =>
      values = values :+ (k, v, k.default)
    }

    assertEquals(values, expectedOptionValues)
  }

  test("optionMap - foreachT") {
    var values: List[Type.Tuple3[Key, Option, Id]] = Nil

    optionMap.foreachT { pair => // no parameter untupling :(
      values = values :+ (pair._1, pair._2, pair._1.default)
    }

    assertEquals(values, expectedOptionValues)
  }

  test("optionMap - foreachK") {
    var values: List[Type.Tuple3[Key, Option, Id]] = Nil

    optionMap.foreachK {
      [A] => (k: Key[A], v: Option[A]) => // need explicit types :(
        values = values :+ (k, v, k.default)
    }

    assertEquals(values, expectedOptionValues)
  }

  test("idMap - apply & updated") {
    assertEquals(idMap(intKey), 1)
    assertEquals(idMap(strKey), "hello")
    assertEquals(idMap.updated(strKey, "yo")(strKey), "yo")
  }

  test("idMap - foreach") {
    var values: List[Type.Tuple3[Key, Id, Id]] = Nil

    idMap.foreach { (k, v) =>
      values = values :+ (k, v, k.default)
    }

    assertEquals(values, expectedIdValues)
  }

  test("idMap - foreachT") {
    var values: List[Type.Tuple3[Key, Id, Id]] = Nil

    idMap.foreachT { pair =>
      values = values :+ (pair._1, pair._2, pair._1.default)
    }

    assertEquals(values, expectedIdValues)
  }

  test("idMap - foreachK") {
    var values: List[Type.Tuple3[Key, Id, Id]] = Nil

    idMap.foreachK {
      [A] => (k: Key[A], v: A) =>
        values = values :+ (k, v, k.default)
    }

    assertEquals(values, expectedIdValues)
  }
```

And now, the support cast that makes this work:

```scala
import scala.language.implicitConversions // old style, but whatever

type Id[A] = A

type Type[F[_]] <: (Any { type T })


object Type {

  type Tuple2[F[_], G[_]] <: (Any { type T })

  type Tuple3[F[_], G[_], H[_]] <: (Any { type T })
}


implicit def wrap[F[_], A](value: F[A]): Type[F] =
  value.asInstanceOf[Type[F]]

implicit def wrapT2[F[_], G[_], A](value: (F[A], G[A])): Type.Tuple2[F, G] =
  value.asInstanceOf[Type.Tuple2[F, G]]

implicit def wrapT2_P1[F[_], A](t: (F[A], A)): Type.Tuple2[F, Id] = wrapT2[F, Id, A](t)

implicit def wrapT3[F[_], G[_], H[_], A](value: (F[A], G[A], H[A])): Type.Tuple3[F, G, H] =
  value.asInstanceOf[Type.Tuple3[F, G, H]]

implicit def wrapT3_P1[F[_], G[_], A](value: (F[A], A, A)): Type.Tuple3[F, Id, Id] =
  value.asInstanceOf[Type.Tuple3[F, Id, Id]]

implicit def wrapT3_P1_P2[F[_], G[_], A](value: (F[A], G[A], A)): Type.Tuple3[F, G, Id] =
  value.asInstanceOf[Type.Tuple3[F, G, Id]]


implicit def unwrap[F[_]](value: Type[F]): F[value.T] =
  value.asInstanceOf[F[value.T]]

implicit def unwrapT2[F[_], G[_]](value: Type.Tuple2[F, G]): (F[value.T], G[value.T]) =
  value.asInstanceOf[(F[value.T], G[value.T])]

implicit def unwrapT3[F[_], G[_], H[_]](value: Type.Tuple3[F, G, H]): (F[value.T], G[value.T], H[value.T]) =
  value.asInstanceOf[(F[value.T], G[value.T], H[value.T])]
```

Comment: I just realized that the `foreach` method here is unsafe, as the caller can provide type param `A` explicitly, which would be unsound as there is no guarantee that all records will contain `A`. So we're stuck with `foreachT` and `foreachK`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative solution, using dependent types. In general I like it better, it's more obvious to me what's going on.

```scala
import scala.language.implicitConversions

type Id[A] = A

implicit def wrapId[A](a: A): Id[A] = a

implicit def unwrapId[A](a: Id[A]): A = a


case class Key[A](caption: String, default: A)

val boolKey = Key[Boolean]("bool", false)
val intKey = Key[Int]("int", 0)
val strKey = Key[String]("str", "")


type KTuple[K[_], V[_]] = {
  type T;
  type Pair = (K[T], V[T]);
}

implicit def KTuple[K[_], V[_], A](value: (K[A], V[A])): KTuple[K, V]#Pair = value.asInstanceOf[KTuple[K, V]#Pair]

implicit def KTuple_P1[K[_], A](value: (K[A], A)): KTuple[K, Id]#Pair = value.asInstanceOf[KTuple[K, Id]#Pair]

class MapK[K[_], V[_]](rawMap: Map[K[Any], V[Any]]) {

  def foreachK(f: [A] => (K[A], V[A]) => Unit): Unit = {
    rawMap.foreach(f.asInstanceOf[((K[Any], V[Any])) => Unit])
  }

  def foreach(f: KTuple[K, V]#Pair => Unit): Unit = {
    rawMap.foreach { pair =>
      f(pair.asInstanceOf[KTuple[K, V]#Pair])
    }
  }
}

object MapK {

  def create[K[_], V[_]](pairs: KTuple[K, V]#Pair*): MapK[K, V] = {
    val x: List[KTuple[K, V]#Pair] = pairs.toList
    val y: List[(K[Any], V[Any])] = x.map(t => t.asInstanceOf[(K[Any], V[Any])])
    new MapK(Map(y: _*))
  }

}

val idMap = MapK.create[Key, Id](
  boolKey -> false,
  intKey -> 1,
  strKey -> "a",
)

val optionMap = MapK.create[Key, Option](
  intKey -> Some(1),
  strKey -> Some("a")
)

type T3[A] = (Key[A], A, A)

var log = List[KTuple[Key, Option]#Pair]()

idMap.foreach { (k, v) =>
  log = log.appended(KTuple(k, Some(v)))
}

def doSomething[A, V[_]](k: Key[A], v: V[A]): Unit = println(s"$k -> v")

optionMap.foreachK {
  [A] => (k: Key[A], v: Option[A]) => {
    doSomething(k, v.get)
    doSomething(k, v)
    log = log :+ KTuple((k, v))
  }
}
```

I wrote up a blog post with more details, will publish soon after some editing. Still looking for better approaches and improvements though.